# Chamar uma popup JSF de um Managed Bean

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Eu uso esse JavaScript para chamar uma `popup` em `JSF`:

```
function showMyPage() { 
    window.open('./showMyPage.xhtml','mywindow', 'resizable=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,height=450,width=530,top=145,left=235');
    return true;
}
```

Mas, eu quero chamá-la direto de um `Managed Bean`, isso é possível?

Exemplo, Eu tenho a seguinte condição, de uma `p:dataTable`:

```
<p:column >
    <h:commandLink action="#{tabelasBean.list(ind)}" >  
        <i class="cus-find"></i> 
    </h:commandLink>  
</p:column>
```

Eu quero chamar a popup pelo Managed Bean, isso é possível?

```
public String list(InfoListVO ind){         
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("InfoListVO ", ind);

    //aqui quero retornar minha popup direto do Managed Bean
    return "myPage";
}
```

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com o primefaces basta fazer isso: `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('nomeDoDialog').show();");`

Passei a resposta através do primefaces porque você o colocou nas tags da pergunta.

Comment: Eu conseguiria fazer isso do richfaces da mesma forma RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("#{rich:component('popup')}.hide(); return false;"); ? Obrigado pela resposta !

Comment: Já tem muito tempo que abandonei o richfaces e uso apenas o primefaces, mas você pode ver se este link te ajuda no richfaces: http://entjavastuff.blogspot.com.br/2010/09/richfaces-modal-panel.html          Caso a responta tenha sanado a sua dúvida por favor não esqueça de marca-la como correta ;)

Comment: Só complementando é o widgetVar do dialog não o id.

Comment: Isso mesmo, onde coloqque 'nomeDoDialog' é o parametro widgetVar  do Dialog, obrigado @Rafael

Comment: Eu acabei usando dessa forma, mas seu exemplo funcionou corretamente:

Comment: <p:commandLink action="#{tableBean.list(ind)}" oncomplete="showMyPage()">  
        <i class="cus-find"></i> 
   </p:commandLink>                   Obrigado !